How to use turtle.distance(x) over members of a list of turtles?
I'm trying to do collision detection over the members of a list of turtles, so that a variable returns a Boolean to break a while true loop. It works with ONE of the turtles, but not the others. It also only prints the distance (for debug) for the one that collision works with. What's confusing is the exact same syntax used in the collision function works just fine in the ball/wall collision detection loops.
import turtle
from turtle import Screen
import random
from random import randrange

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(500, 500)
screen.title('Balls Bounce')

friend = turtle.Turtle()
friend.shape('turtle')
friend.color('green')
friend.turtlesize(3)

def friendUp():
    friend.setheading(90)
    friend.forward(45)

def friendDown():
    friend.setheading(270)
    friend.forward(45)

def friendRight():
    friend.setheading(0)
    friend.forward(45)

def friendLeft():
    friend.setheading(180)
    friend.forward(45)

screen.onkey(friendUp, "Up")
screen.onkey(friendLeft, "Left")
screen.onkey(friendRight, "Right")
screen.onkey(friendDown, "Down")
screen.listen()

def createBall():
    ball = turtle.Turtle(shape="circle")
    ball.penup()
    ball.color("Red")
    ball.turtlesize(3)
    ball.setheading(randrange(361))
    ball.forward(5)
    return ball

balls = []
for i in range(5):
    b = createBall()
    balls.append(b)

bodySize = 80
halfBodySize = bodySize / 2
collisionDistance = 5
isCollision = False

def collision(balls, friend):
    distance = 0
    for b in balls:
        distance = b.distance(friend)
        print(distance // 1)
        if distance < halfBodySize:
            print('Collision!')
            global isCollision
            isCollision = True
            break
        return isCollision

while True:
    collision(balls, friend)
    if isCollision == True:
        break
    for b in balls:
        b.forward(5)
        xPos = b.position()[0]
        yPos = b.position()[1]
        if xPos > 250 or xPos < -250:
            b.forward(-5)
            b.setheading(randrange(361))
        if yPos > 250 or yPos < -250:
            b.forward(-5)
            b.setheading(randrange(361))

screen.mainloop()

I've tried using map and enumerate, but they keep returning issues that I can't seem to figure out. For instance, using enumerate returns tuple issues, and I'm not sure I set up the syntax for it correctly. Map has similar issues.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Please think carefully about the logic. When should return isCollision happen: after the loop has finished checking the balls, or at the end of each time through the loop? Therefore, should that code be inside the loop, or outside? Is it where it should be?

Or look at it another way: you have a list of balls, and you want to know whether "this ball is colliding with the player" is true for any of them - yes? So, that has many standard solutions, and is easily enough researched (I've added a separate duplicate link for that). It seems that you got unlucky enough to make a mistake in each of several approaches. But a big part of the problem is your general understanding. If you are describing it like "using enumerate returns tuple issues" then you need to study what the words mean, how the tools work, and how to make sense of errors.

(Similarly: incorrect syntax can only cause a SyntaxError or some subtype of that, such as IndentationError or TabError. if you're getting a wrong result, that's either because of incorrect logic or simply not understanding how a specific tool works.)

return isCollision needs to be indented one level further, inside the if that detects collision:
def collision(balls, friend):
    for b in balls:
        distance = b.distance(friend)
        print(distance // 1)

        if distance < halfBodySize:
            print('Collision!')
            return True

    return False

If it's outside the if, it'll always return whatever the first ball-friend collision result was and never make it past the first iteration of the loop.
No need for global--just return the value and use it directly in the caller:
if collision(balls, friend):
    # there was a collision between a ball and friend

You can also remove your print() calls, at which point consider using any:
def collision(balls, friend):
    return any(b.distance(friend) < halfBodySize for b in balls)

Here's a minimal proof of correctness:
from random import randint
from turtle import Screen, Turtle


def check_collision(ball, balls):
    return any(b.distance(ball) < HALF_BODY_SIZE for b in balls)


def reposition():
    for t in turtles:
        t.goto(randint(-w, w), randint(-h, h))

    friend.color("green")

    if check_collision(friend, balls):
        friend.color("red")

    screen.update()


HALF_BODY_SIZE = 60
screen = Screen()
w, h = screen.screensize()
screen.tracer(0)
turtles = []

for _ in range(35):
    t = Turtle(shape="circle")
    turtles.append(t)
    t.shapesize(3)
    t.penup()

friend, balls = turtles[-1], turtles[:-1]
reposition()
screen.onclick(lambda *_: reposition())
screen.mainloop()

As an aside, use snake_case for functions and variables, not camelCase, per PEP-8 convention.
Also prefer from turtle import Screen, Turtle to avoid confusing the functional and OOP interfaces. Your current code never uses from turtle import Screen, which can be caught with a linter like flake 8.
